# Unable to add Solution to TFS 2010 due to existing (invisible)binding

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have a smallish utility library I made that I had created in TFS Beta 2 to test out TFS.  I now have TFS rc1 installed(and Beta 2 uninstalled) and am trying to add my Solution to TFS.

I get an error saying that it is already bound to my old TFS, which was on a different system then this one.  Strangely, when I go into Source Control and look at the bindings it says there aren't any.  Also, I manually deleted the .vss and .vsc files and it still does it.

Ideas?  I looked through the numerous other SO topics related to this but unless I missed one none of them are dealing with my issue.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the [TFS Sidekicks from Attrice](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/).  They have a workspace sidekick, you can pretty quickly find your old machine and unbind/delete that workspace from TFS.

Once you install:

- VS Menu Bar
- Tools
- Team Foundation Sidekicks
- Workspace Sidekick
- Owner will defult to you, just clear machine name
- Search
- Select old workspace, click the red X to delete

Comment: @Refracted Paladin - TFS 2010 RC or just the client and still TFS Server 2008?

Comment: @Refracted Paladin - I'm afraid you'll have to go the command line route until that tool is updated then, not too much work though: http://blog.cognitioninfotech.com/2008/06/how-to-delete-workspace-from-tfs-team.html  I only have Beta 2 to test with, but the I don't think the functionality has changed in that department since.

Comment: Thanks!  For future reference I actually needed the command that was in the comments on that page. `tf workspaces /remove:*` in order to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had old server entries too and I fixed it by using the workspace sidekick mentioned here and then using the command line to get the rest that the tool couldn't find.